# Equivalent for MvcHtmlString in ASP.NET 5?

Tags: html-helper, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there an equivalent for MvcHtmlString in ASP.NET 5 ?
Otherwise, how can we render HTML output from my custom HTMLHelper method properly ?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

There is no longer need for `MvcHtmlString` (which added on top of `HtmlString` for compatibility reasons) so you can simply use `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering.HtmlString`.

As you can easily notice, the ViewComponents and Helpers of Asp.Net 5 are also using (by returning) the same `HtmlString` to the views.

**Update (for ASP.NET Core 3.1):**

You need to use [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.html.htmlstring?view=aspnetcore-3.1) instead.

Comment: what is the equivalent part of MVCHtmlString.Create() in Core 3.1

Comment: @KarthicG, `new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString(...)`?

Comment: Thanks @haim770 ,it is working fine in cs file but i have a doubt in View page.In Htmlpage==>@Html.Raw instead of MVCHtml.Create().Is that right?

Comment: @KarthicG, Yes.

Comment: For ASP.NET Core 5, sometimes using/returning `IHtmlContent` (which is implemented by `HtmlString`) could be sufficient.

Answer (score 46):

Asp .Net Core (v.5) replaced `MvcHtmlString` for a new `HtmlString` type. Don't confuse this with the [HtmlString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.htmlstring.aspx) type that is a part of the System.Web namespace introduced in .NET 4.0 (`MvcHtmlString` inherits from this type).

**NOTE:** After April 28, 2016 the `HtmlString` type was moved to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions` package. Remember to include this in your project.json in the dependencies node.

Additionally, you need to declare the using directive

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
```

or declare it by its fully qualified name:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString
```

If you want more information on the HtmlString type look at the HtmlAbstractions package source code located [here](https://github.com/aspnet/HtmlAbstractions)

Comment: what is the equivalent part of MVCHtmlString.Create() in Core 3.1

Comment: For ASP.NET Core 5, sometimes using/returning `IHtmlContent` (which is implemented by `HtmlString`) instead of `HtmlString` could be sufficient.

Comment: `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions` has been deprecated, so if anyone knows an alternative package you could reference in non-web projects, I am all ears...