# Using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Its a **.Net Core 2.0** application running on **Visual Studio 2017**
I want to display an HTML string returned on the View.

I have added the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions** [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.Abstractions/) to my application, and I want to display an HTML sting on the Razor view, this is how my CSHTML looks like

```
@model EDMTLC.Models.QuickResultViewModel
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
<div>@Html.Display(Model.ResultHTML) </div>
<div>TEST</div>
```

I don't think @Html.Display is the way I should be doing. In previous version .Net I used to to

```
<div>
    <text> @MvcHtmlString.Create(Model.ReportHTML)</text>
 </div>
```

but this will not work anymore with Core 2.0

Can someone help with an example? I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602202/equivalent-for-mvchtmlstring-in-asp-net-5/39537346) thread, but it didn't help!

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

A more elegant solution is to build an extension method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
public static class StringExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Convert a standard string into a htmlstring for rendering in a view
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static HtmlString ToHtmlString(this string value)
    {
        return new HtmlString(value);
    }
}
```

In your _ViewImports file, include the namespace if required:

```
@using MyProject.Extensions
```

Now in your views you will be able to do:

```
<div>@Model.ReportHTML.ToHtmlString()</div>
```

I'd advise doing additional sanitization in a real world app but this should answer the OP's question.

Comment: This is beautiful

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `@Html.Raw()`? It should display the value as raw string, without encoding.

```
<pre>
    <code>@Html.Raw(Model.ReportHTML)</code>
</pre>
```

This should work in `Asp.Net Core Mvc 2.0` and previous versions as well, without the need of installing additional NuGet packages.

### Notes

1. In order to use `@Html.Display()`, if you're passing a string expression into the argument, that argument has to match one of your properties defined in your view model.

   ```
   // This doesn't work
   @Html.Display(Model.ResultHTML)

   // This works but it encodes your HTML
   @Html.Display("ResultHtml")
   ```
2. Or you can use `@Html.DisplayFor()` and pass a lamba expression to avoid magic strings in your View

   ```
   // This works but it encodes your HTML
   @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ResultHTML)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is to avoid `Html.Raw` for security reasons amongst others, better to use
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlContentBuilder`
like so

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlContentBuilder DatabaseList = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.HtmlContentBuilder();
DatabaseList.AppendHtml("The list of databases on this server is: " + "<br />");
foreach (var db in dbList) {
    DatabaseList.AppendHtml(db.ToString() + "<br />");
}
```