# What is the equivalent of MvcHtmlString.Create() method in Asp.Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I have implemented the project of migrating Asp.Net MVC into Asp.Net Core 3.1.

**HomeController.cs**

```
   static Regex regex = new Regex("(</?)script", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
   public static MvcHtmlString EmbeddedTemplate(EntityBase entityBase, MvcHtmlString template, string defaultString)
    {
        return MvcHtmlString.Create("<script type=\"template\" id=\"{0}\" data-toString=\"{2}\">{1}</script>"
                            .Formato(entityBase.Compose(EntityBaseKeys.Template),
                            regex.Replace(template.ToHtmlString(), m => m.Value + "X"),
                            defaultString));
    }
```

I have followed the link: [.NET CORE MvcHtmlString(TextboxFor, LabelFor).ToString() Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53413899/net-core-mvchtmlstringtextboxfor-labelfor-tostring-error). Here it is suggested to use
IHtmlContent(Interface). But it does not have a Create() method.

And also what is the equivalent of MvcHtmlString?
Kindly suggest on alternative solution on this.

Comment: Did you check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29602202/equivalent-for-mvchtmlstring-in-asp-net-5)? Is says about `HtmlString` class, which exist in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html` namespace in .Net core

Comment: Yes checked but it doesn't have create() method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got it.
Asp.Net Core replaced MvcHtmlString for a new HtmlString type.

```
static Regex regex = new Regex("(</?)script", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
public static HtmlString EmbeddedTemplate(EntityBase entityBase, MvcHtmlString template, string defaultString)
{
    return new HtmlString("<script type=\"template\" id=\"{0}\" data-toString=\"{2}\">{1}</script>"
                        .Formato(entityBase.Compose(EntityBaseKeys.Template),
                        regex.Replace(template.ToHtmlString(), m => m.Value + "X"),
                        defaultString));
}
```

Additionally, you need to declare the using directive

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
```